# Get error "InvalidRequest" when use AdMob in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob

I'm really confusing ! I get this error randomly, Sometime the code worked (yesterday code went okay) but sometime not (today it returned "InvalidRequest" error).

I put this code in every page of my app

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.MyModel;
        LoadAd();
    }  

void LoadAd()
    {
        AdView av = new AdView()
        {
            AdUnitID = "ca-app-pub-...‏‏‏‏‏",
            Format = AdFormats.Banner,
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top,
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left,                
        };
        av.FailedToReceiveAd += av_FailedToReceiveAd;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(av);
        AdRequest ar = new AdRequest();
        ar.ForceTesting = true;
        av.LoadAd(ar);
    }

void av_FailedToReceiveAd(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ErrorCode.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that this error is mostly due to incorrect ad unit ids.
Check your adid, and make sure that its correct and doesnt have any space

Comment: Thank you for answering an question from Sep. last year ^^ but I've  found out the problem since it's because network conection that make my app couldn't connect to google admob service.

Comment: Ok, thats good.I had the same challenge you had,but mine was caused by space at the end of the adunitid, you will think Google can remove whitespaces